# Ubuntu Install from other Linux Distro

Tags: system-installation

Let's say I have a **s390** Suse zLinux running (or any other Non-Ubuntu Linux). Is there a way to install Ubuntu with a sort of installer program to a new disk (including makes it able to boot) ? If yes, how does it work ? (no x86 involved !)

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of ways of achieving this.  One workaround involves Virtualizationusing.  In this instance I'll use [VirtualBox](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=virtualbox&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all).

These are the steps:

- **Create a virtual guest** for installing the OS.  
  (Make the virtual OS small so that the image won't take up a lot of space.  8 Gigs should be sufficient.)
- **Install the desired OS** into the Virtual Guest Machine.
- **Create a disk image** of your guest vdi.
  *For a static size .vdi use:*

  `$ VBoxManage clonehd [vdi-image.vdi] [drive.img] --format RAW`
  *For a dynamic size .vdi use:*
  `$ VBoxManage internalcommands converttoraw [vdi-image.vdi] [drive.img]`
  Replace the [vdi-image.vdi] and [drive.img] for with the vdi image and the destination image for your drive.
- **Copy the image** to your new hard drive using `dd`.
  `$ dd if=output.img of=/dev/sdc bs=4M status=progress`
- **Resize the partitions** the way you want them using [gparted](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gparted&searchon=names).
- **Install the new drive** into the destination computer and boot.

If your destination drive is already partitioned and already have an OS on it , instead of restoring the whole drive use partitions as your source and destination rather than the whole drive.  Use the alternative section `copy parition`.

The initial Ubuntu partition of the new drive in these steps, will be small because of the original small image.  You can increase the partition size using `gparted`.

---

Alternatively you can copy a partition rather than the whole drive.  Use this copy option if you already have data on the destination drive and you what the Ubuntu installation to be on a specific partition.

**Copy partition as source**

- **Locate the partition** in the saved image file.

Run this on the image drive:

```
$ sudo losetup -f --show -P [drive.img]
$ lsb
```

The loop setup will split the partitions into `/dev/loop0p1`, `/dev/loop0p2`, etc. You can identify your desired partition by the size details from the `lsb` output.  You can also mount the partitions in the normal manner to examine them.

- **Copy Partition to partition** to the destination drive with:

Replace [source-partition] and [dest-partition] with: Source: `/dev/loop0p#` (the # is the number of the partition with the OS installation); Destination: `/dev/sdax` (The X represent the partition number for the OS installation to be installed on the destination drive).

```
$ dd if=[source-partition] of=/dev/[destination-partition] bs=4M status=progress
```

After the `dd` copy process completes, mount the `destination partition`, and update grub with these steps:

(The `XX` represent the drive and partition number as in `c1` for `/dev/sdc1`.  The `X` by itself represent the actual drive as in `/dev/sdc`.)

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt
$ for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt/$i"; done
$ sudo chroot /mnt
$ grub-install /dev/sdX
update-grub
exit
$ for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo umount --bind "$i" "/mnt/$i"; done
```

- Now proceed to the two steps above starting with **resize partition**.

---

**Tools used:**

The tools used above are linked to show they are in the default repository of Ubuntu.  You can install those tools using `sudo apt-get` and the tool name.

Comment: Not possible if you run zLinux on IBM Mainframe cause there is no VirtualBox. This goes around my question. sorry

Comment: @malo I mentioned `Virtualbox` as an example.  I'm sure I could help you to follow the steps to achieve this if you were interested.  The keyword in this is `virtualization`.  All Mainframes have `Virtualization`.  The `Virtualbox` could be replaced with `kvm` which is supported on `zLinux`.